# Is there a way to display live calculation with an information taken from mysql database?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I am developing a **web application**, and I need to display a **live calculation** as soon as the fields are filled with the information.

What I mean by a **live calculation** is something as live as a **ng-model in a ng-app**. The problem goes like this:

The user chooses a **product** from a dropdown list, which list's choices are coming from a **mysql database** and the **price** of the **chosen product** should be the **first multiplyer**, while the **second multiplyer** is the next input field where the **customer** should enter how many **pieces** they want.

I tried to take the **price** from the table where **product** is selected but I believe that **php** needs a submission in order to process the data and actually see which product has been selected.

So is there any way to display a live **calculation** and **inform** the **customer** how much their order will cost before they **submit the form**?

Thank you!

---

## Update:

I came few steps further along the way but i got stuck again... so now i do retrieve the value of the chosen product but i fail to do the calculation because javascript says that the retrieved value is not a number (NaN) as soon as i try to do the operation.

This is the code that shows the value of the chosen product

```
<form action="#" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="clientname" class="fields" placeholder="Enter your name " required/>
    <input type="text" name="contactinfo" class="fields" placeholder="Phone or Email" required/>
    <input type="text" name="address" class="fields" placeholder="Street Address" required/>
    <select class='dropdown' name='ordertype' id='ordertype' onchange='productPrice()' required>
        <option value="" disabled selected>Select Product</option>
        <?php
        $query = "SELECT * FROM products";
        $query_run = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);
        while($row = $query_run->fetch_assoc()){
            echo"<option value=".$row['price'].">".$row['name']."</option>";
        }
        ?>
    </select>
    <input ng-model="price" type="number" name="amount" class="fields" placeholder="How many pieces?" required/>
    <button name="placeorder" class="regbutton">Place Order</button>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
function productPrice(){
    var option = document.getElementById("ordertype").selectedIndex;
    var value = document.getElementById("ordertype").options;
    var result = (value[option].value);

    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = result + "$";
}
document.write('<p id="result"></p>' );
</script>
```

but the moment i try to do the calculation and multiply the given output * {{price}} or even when i try to multiply it * 2 it says NaN on page load (it has nothing to do with the dollar sign).

So do you know why is this happening and how can i fix it?

Thanks again!

Comment: You need to look on Ajax

Comment: You can use AJAX to run an asynchronous process, for example, you can get the price of the product and then multiply it with the quantity.

Comment: try to look eventsource

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP code isn't going to know when the data changes, so even though you could use comet or websockets to get data immediately from the PHP code to the browser, you still need to poll the database for changes. It's simpler to just trigger the polling on a schedule from the browser using Ajax.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you idea,

```
var source = new EventSource("demo_sse.php");
source.onmessage = function(event) {
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += event.data + "<br>";
};
<div id="result"></div>
```

demo_sse.php

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');

$time = date('r');
echo "data: The server time is: {$time}\n\n";
flush();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

use jQuery ajax call.
go step by step.
1st get the qty of any product or any thing that the have changed.
on ajax call i guess you are creating a cart. let every thing same just add product or any thing to the cart of your. and get the hole data. 
append the recent value.

in this way the amount you have stored in php that you can have at your client side using ajax call